# Nonce Override in python ccxt

Tags: python, bitcoin, trading, nonce, ccxt

so I keep recieveing this message when trying to place trades using ccxt:

"Timestamp for this request is not valid."

I've read the ccxt manual and it says to override the nonce I should use:

```
class MyBitfinex (ccxt.bitfinex):
    def nonce (self):
        return self.milliseconds ()
```

But I just don't understand how to make this work. I'm not too advanced of a python programmer.

any help is definitely appreciated

Here is the code I am trying to get to run:

```
def BuyAll (symbol):

base = markets[symbol]['base']
quote = markets[symbol]['quote']
Balances = binance.fetchBalance()
quoteBalance = Balances[quote]['free']
stopOut = 0
orderBookPosition = 0

while quoteBalance > stopOut:
    print('quote balance',quoteBalance)
    runningBalance = quoteBalance - stopOut
    orderbook = binance.fetchOrderBook(symbol)


    if (orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][1])*(orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][0])< runningBalance:
        if base == 'BNB':
            quantity = truncate(orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][1],0)
        else:
            quantity = truncate(orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][1],3)
        print('quantity',quantity)
        binance.createLimitBuyOrder(symbol,quantity,orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][0])
        print('Bought' + ' ' + symbol)
        stopOut += (orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][1])*(orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][0])

    elif (runningBalance)/(orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][0]) > 0:

        if base == 'BNB':
            amount = int((runningBalance)/(orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][0]))

        else:
            amount = truncate((runningBalance)/(orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][0]),3)

        print('amount',amount)
        binance.createLimitBuyOrder(symbol,amount,orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][0])
        print('Bought' + ' ' + symbol)
        stopOut += (orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][1])*(orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][0])
    orderBookPosition += 1
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\ccxt\exchange.py",
>   line 209, in fetch
>       response = opener.open(request, timeout=int(self.timeout / 1000))   File
>   "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 471, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)   File "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 581, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 509, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)   File "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 443, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 589, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       MomentumTrader('ETH','BTC')   File "C:/Users/Scott/Desktop/MomentumTraderFifth.py", line 199, in
>   MomentumTrader
>       BuyAll(currencyPair)   File "C:/Users/Scott/Desktop/MomentumTraderFifth.py", line 89, in BuyAll
>       binance.createLimitBuyOrder(symbol,amount,orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][0])
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\ccxt\exchange.py",
>   line 646, in createLimitBuyOrder
>       return self.create_limit_buy_order(market, amount, price, params)   File
>   "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\ccxt\exchange.py",
>   line 634, in create_limit_buy_order
>       return self.create_order(market, 'limit', 'buy', amount, price, params)   File
>   "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\ccxt\exchanges.py",
>   line 986, in create_order
>       response = self.privatePostOrder(self.extend(order, params))   File
>   "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\ccxt\exchanges.py",
>   line 1049, in request
>       response = self.fetch(url, method, headers, body)   File "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\ccxt\exchange.py",
>   line 244, in fetch
>       self.raise_error(error, url, method, e, details)   File "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\ccxt\exchange.py",
>   line 181, in raise_error
>       details, ccxt.errors.ExchangeNotAvailable: binance POST https://www.binance.com/api/v1/order 400 Bad Request  (possible
>   reasons: invalid API keys, bad or old nonce, exchange is down or
>   offline, on maintenance, DDoS protection, rate-limiting,
>   {"code":-1021,"msg":"Timestamp for this request is not valid."})

Answer (score 1):

Please, read the [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/kroitor/ccxt/wiki/Manual#troubleshooting) section very carefully from ccxt library Manual. This is due to expired keys. Did you try it with another keypair?

Also, for Bitfinex, setting the nonce to milliseconds is not needed, it is in milliseconds already by default. Try this sample and see if it works for you:

```
import ccxt

bitfinex = ccxt.bitfinex ({
    'apiKey': '4FlEDtxDl35gdEiobnfZ72vJeZteE4Bb7JdvqzjIjHq',
    'secret': 'D4DXM8DZdHuAq9YptUsb42aWT1XBnGlIJgLi8a7tzFH',
})

print(bitfinex.fetch_balance())
```

If it does work then you should create a fresh new keypair and everything should be normal from there on. Don't worry, you won't loose funds on your account if you create a new keypair.

Comment: But the keys are brand new. How often should I need to make a new set of keys? I'm able to access my balances but when it comes to placing a trade that's when I get the message.

Comment: Can you show your code?

https://github.com/kroitor/ccxt/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#how-to-submit-an-issue

- your language version, ccxt library version
- which method you're trying to call in particular
- a full code snippet you're having difficulties with (avoid one-liners)
- paste the full stacktrace (error output) of that snippet in verbose mode as is, unchanged

We need that if you want us to help quicker.

Comment: Hi Igor, so I have uploaded the code I was using along with the error message that accompanies it. Its so weird how some times it works and then sometimes it gives me that time stamp BS.

Comment: I really don't understand why this is a problem at all considering that when I submit a request it is carrying the timestamp that is associated with the moment I submitted it. Their are limitations which prevent older requests from being processed but all my requests are instant.

Comment: Hi, Scott! This is a different code for binance, not bitfinex...
That error on Binance means your system time is out of sync with their clock by >5 seconds... Check your time UTC-alignment.
Binance doc: An additional parameter, recvWindow, may be sent to specific the number of milliseconds after timestamp the request is valid for. If recvWindow is not sent, it defaults to 5000 millisecond. Try passing a larger recvWindow if your connection to Binance is slow:
`binance.createLimitBuyOrder(symbol,amount,orderbook['asks'][orderBookPosition][0], {'recvWindow':10000})` (or 20000)...